# How to group an array by its nested array elements using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, group-by

I have an array of `song` elements that contains an array of `artists` related to the song

I would like to group `songs` by `artists` the songs contain. Given the following dataset, here's how I'd like the data to be formatted:

Criteria:

- A song should only be a part of one group, so if a song has multiple artists, it should be stored under a grouping called `groupedArtists: "1,2"` (might be a better naming convention)
- It shouldn't matter what order the artists are listed in. If a song has artists `1` and `2`, and another song has artists `2` and `1`, then both should be grouped under `groupedArtists: "1,2"`

```
var ungroupedData = [
  {
    trackId: 1,
    title: 'track 1',
    artists: [
      {
        artistId: 1,
        name: 'artist 1',
      },
      {
        artistId: 2,
        name: 'artist 2',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    trackId: 2,
    title: 'track 2',
    artists: [
      {
        artistId: 1,
        name: 'artist 1',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    trackId: 3,
    title: 'track 3',
    artists: [
      {
        artistId: 2,
        name: 'artist 2',
      },
      {
        artistId: 3,
        name: 'artist 3',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    trackId: 4,
    title: 'track 4',
    artists: [
      {
        artistId: 2,
        name: 'artist 2',
      },
      {
        artistId: 1,
        name: 'artist 1',
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

Below is the desired format of my data. Again, I wish to not add a song to a group if it simply **contains** an artist, it **must match** every single artist to be added to the grouping (for example, if there is a song with just an `artist 1` it must not be added to a grouping called `groupedArtists: "1,2"`. Therefore, a grouping called `groupedArtists: "1"` would be created if it has not been created already.

```
var groupedData = [
  {
    artistGroup: '1,2', <-- definitely open to group naming suggestions
    songs: [
      {
        trackId: 1, <-- this track has artists 1 & 2
        title: 'track 1',
        artists: [
          {
            artistId: 1,
            name: 'artist 1',
          },
          {
            artistId: 2,
            name: 'artist 2',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        trackId: 4, <-- this track has artists 2 & 1 but they are still grouped together
        title: 'track 4',
        artists: [
          {
            artistId: 2,
            name: 'artist 2',
          },
          {
            artistId: 1,
            name: 'artist 1',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    artistGroup: '1',
    songs: [
      {
        trackId: 2, <-- track 2 only has artist 1 so `artistGroup: "1"` is created.
        title: 'track 2',
        artists: [
          {
            artistId: 1,
            name: 'artist 1',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    artistGroup: '2,3',
    songs: [
      {
        trackId: 3, <-- this song has artists 2 and 3 so we create `artistGroup: "2,3"`
        title: 'track 3',
        artists: [
          {
            artistId: 2,
            name: 'artist 2',
          },
          {
            artistId: 3,
            name: 'artist 3',
          },
        ],
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off using a dictionary which maps the name of artists (or combinations of artists) to an array of their songs. For example:

```
let groupData = {};
for(let song of ungroupedData) {
    let group_name = song.artists.map(artist => artist.artistId).sort().join(',');
    if(!(group_name in groupData)) {
        groupData[group_name] = [];
    }
    groupData[group_name].push(song);
}
```

Note the sorting of the artists to ensure a standard representation.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check this solution, (i have edited the answer now to eliminate duplicate artistGroups)?

```js
var ungroupedData = [
  {
    trackId: 1,
    title: 'track 1',
    artists: [
      {
        artistId: 1,
        name: 'artist 1',
      },
      {
        artistId: 2,
        name: 'artist 2',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    trackId: 2,
    title: 'track 2',
    artists: [
      {
        artistId: 1,
        name: 'artist 1',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    trackId: 3,
    title: 'track 3',
    artists: [
      {
        artistId: 2,
        name: 'artist 2',
      },
      {
        artistId: 3,
        name: 'artist 3',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    trackId: 4,
    title: 'track 4',
    artists: [
      {
        artistId: 2,
        name: 'artist 2',
      },
      {
        artistId: 1,
        name: 'artist 1',
      },
    ],
  },
];

var artistsoriginal = [];
var groupedData = [];
var isPresent = false;

ungroupedData.forEach((trk) => {
    
    if(trk.artists.length === 1) {
      groupedData.push({
        artistGroup: trk.artists[0].artistId.toString(),
        songs: [trk]
      });
    }

    if(trk.artists.length > 1) {
      let artistsArray = [];
      trk.artists.forEach((ats) => {
        artistsArray.push(ats.artistId);
      });
      const isEqual = (artistsArray.every(val => artistsoriginal.includes(val)));
      if(!isEqual) {
        artistsoriginal.push(...artistsArray);
        groupedData.push({
          artistGroup: artistsArray.toString(),
          songs: [trk]
        });
      }
    }
}
);
console.log(groupedData);
```

Answer (score 0):

It feels a bit verbose and there's room for condensing it, but here's what I would do (comments and variables should provide clarity).

```
const dataWithGroupedIds = ungroupedData.map(track => {
  // get all the artist Ids for that track in an array
  track.allArtists = track.artists.map(t => t.artistId) 
  // remove duplicates and sort
  track.allArtists = [...new Set(track.allArtists)].sort((a,b) => a-b)
  return track
})

// get all the artistGroups and remove duplicates
const artistGroups = dataWithGroupedIds.map(t => t.allArtists).filter((t={},a=>!(t[a]=a in t))); 

// get the songs for each artistGroup
const groupedData = artistGroups.map(artistIds => {
  songs = dataWithGroupedIds.filter(track => JSON.stringify(track.allArtists) === JSON.stringify(artistIds))
  return { artistGroup: artistIds, songs } // return in desired format
})
```

Demo:

```js
const ungroupedData = [
  {
    trackId: 1,
    title: 'track 1',
    artists: [
      {
        artistId: 1,
        name: 'artist 1',
      },
      {
        artistId: 2,
        name: 'artist 2',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    trackId: 2,
    title: 'track 2',
    artists: [
      {
        artistId: 1,
        name: 'artist 1',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    trackId: 3,
    title: 'track 3',
    artists: [
      {
        artistId: 2,
        name: 'artist 2',
      },
      {
        artistId: 3,
        name: 'artist 3',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    trackId: 4,
    title: 'track 4',
    artists: [
      {
        artistId: 2,
        name: 'artist 2',
      },
      {
        artistId: 1,
        name: 'artist 1',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    trackId: 5,
    title: 'track 5',
    artists: [
      {
        artistId: 2,
        name: 'artist 2',
      },
      {
        artistId: 1,
        name: 'artist 1',
      },
    ],
  },
]

const dataWithGroupedIds = ungroupedData.map(track => {
  // get all the artist Ids for that track in an array
  track.allArtists = track.artists.map(t => t.artistId) 
  // remove duplicates and sort
  track.allArtists = [...new Set(track.allArtists)].sort((a,b) => a-b) 
  return track
})

// get all the artistGroups and remove duplicates
const artistGroups = dataWithGroupedIds.map(t => t.allArtists).filter((t={},a=>!(t[a]=a in t))); 

// get the songs for each artistGroup
const groupedData = artistGroups.map(artistIds => {
  songs = dataWithGroupedIds.filter(track => JSON.stringify(track.allArtists) === JSON.stringify(artistIds))
  return { artistGroup: artistIds, songs } // return in desired format
})

console.log(groupedData)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If you want to do it using map, you can refer below code.


var ungroupedData = [
  {
    trackId: 1,
    title: 'track 1',
    artists: [
      {
        artistId: 1,
        name: 'artist 1',
      },
      {
        artistId: 2,
        name: 'artist 2',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    trackId: 2,
    title: 'track 2',
    artists: [
      {
        artistId: 1,
        name: 'artist 1',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    trackId: 3,
    title: 'track 3',
    artists: [
      {
        artistId: 2,
        name: 'artist 2',
      },
      {
        artistId: 3,
        name: 'artist 3',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    trackId: 4,
    title: 'track 4',
    artists: [
      {
        artistId: 2,
        name: 'artist 2',
      },
      {
        artistId: 1,
        name: 'artist 1',
      },
    ],
  },
]
    var myMap = new Map();
    for (var i=0 ; i<ungroupedData.length; i++){
        var artistIds=[];
        
        //document.write(ungroupedData[i].artists[0].artistId);
        ungroupedData[i].artists.forEach(function(artist){
            artistIds.push(artist.artistId);
        })
        artistIds.sort();
        console.log('artistIds',artistIds.join());
    
        if(myMap.has(artistIds.join())){
            debugger;
            var myExistingKey= myMap.get(artistIds.join());
            myExistingKey.songs.push(ungroupedData[i])
            myMap.set(artistIds.join(),myExistingKey)
        }
        else{
            myMap.set(artistIds.join(),{songs:[ungroupedData[i]]})
        }
        
        //myMap.set('1',1);
    }
    console.log('M', myMap);
```